Grouping Nuxt 3 tags
I am currently trying to group my tags inside the head of my nuxt 3 application. What I mean by this is, I want my meta tags to all be together, all my scripts to be together and styling etc… my nuxt.config.ts is set up correctly.
While it is ordered in Nuxt it is not ordered when inspecting my html page. Is there a way to group these so that a link tag is not found in between my meta tags?
My HTML head is showing:
<meta etc..>
<link etc…>
<meta etc…>

But I want it to show:
<meta etc…>
<meta etc…>
<link etc…>


You will need to use tagPosition with unjs. It doesn‘t really matter though since you are using nuxt, you have layouts and pages and this will cause tag deduping, so you don‘t need to worry about your link, meta, and script tags all being grouped. Sometimes the script needs to come last so it isn‘t feasible to expect everything to be grouped.
